# Debian package with System Requirements validation?

Tags: packaging, debconf

Is it possible to create, through the use of debconf, a package that validates the minimum system requirements to run the software? Is debconf pre-install config script the way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: And if the system requirements are not met, what would the package do?

Comment: Either display warnings or abort the installation. Is there a standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can display warnings during package installation. However, aborting the installation is a **bad idea** - you will leave the package system in a broken state and until the user removes your package, every package installation will end with an attempt to finish installing yours. That will be *terrible* user experience.

You can use a `postinst` script to do this - I suggest `postinst` since you might have to install packages as dependencies to detect the hardware, etc., and [packaging policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-maintscriptprompt) specifies that prompting be done in `postinst`:

> If a package has a vitally important piece of information to pass to
>   the user (such as "don't run me as I am, you must edit the following
>   configuration files first or you risk your system emitting
>   badly-formatted messages"), it should display this in the config or
>   postinst script and prompt the user to hit return to acknowledge the
>   message. Copyright messages do not count as vitally important (they
>   belong in /usr/share/doc/package/copyright); neither do instructions
>   on how to use a program (these should be in on-line documentation,
>   where all the users can see them).
>
> Any necessary prompting should almost always be confined to the config
>   or postinst script. If it is done in the postinst, it should be
>   protected with a conditional so that unnecessary prompting doesn't
>   happen if a package's installation fails and the postinst is called
>   with abort-upgrade, abort-remove or abort-deconfigure.

With `debconf`, a [`db_input` command](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/debconf_specification.html) with priority `high` or `critical` could display the warning.

It might be better to write a wrapper script for your software executable which checks the requirements, and shows a more visible message, with possibly an option to uninstall your package.